An identity involving four random variables that are jointly Gaussian with mean zero.
The identity which I woulk like see proven is:
$$E[WXYZ]=E[WX]E[YZ]+E[WY]E[XZ]+E[WZ]E[XY]$$
Where is the expectation value, and $W,X,Y,Z$ are random variables with mean zero that are jointly Gaussian.
If you can provide a reference with a proof, even better.
Thanks!

This is the Wick-Isserlis' theorem. The Wikipedia articles offer a good proof outline.

Thanks, I forgot that there was such a thing in QFT.
